# make a simple pie chart directive with d3js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to make a simple pie chart directive with d3js and angular.js [based on this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235)

The datas are loaded with $resource. The datas are available inside the directive as a json object named 'values', but i don't know how to use them with d3.

i tried

```
json = JSON.parse( values );
```

but it doesn't work.

here is the whole code: http://plnkr.co/edit/XDyWlLY5R1ZZ4sKn5n3v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two issues

1. Values isn't a string - it has already been parsed and is an array of objects.
2. The slices representing each object are being and colored according to their `population` and `age` properties. Both of those are currently undefined, so you'll have to add that information to the JSON that you load or change how the slices are sized and colored.